# Splash screen jumping to the side on iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

I am developing an ionic application. I have hit a problem where on an iOS device the splash screen jumps to the right. This happens only on iOS and i have made all of the correct changes to the sizes of the splash screen. I am using the Cordova splash screen plugin, I have uninstalled and re-installed this only to have the same problem. No errors are thrown up - I was just looking to know if anyone else has or has had this problem. Thanks.

Comment: what is your splash screen pixel ?? make sure you have 2208pixel of your splash screen

Comment: Which version of iOS is this? What is the output of `cordova plugins` (the splashscreen plugin version)? Does this happen with the latest master version? `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen`